# Why risk parameters are not shown by finance websites for some money market funds?

Tags: investing

For instruments like stocks, MFs (other than money market funds), one can easily find the risk parameters like alpha, beta, Sharpe ratio, etc, from finance websites. However, such parameters are not present for some money market funds. For example, I am not able to find risk parameters for SPAXX and other govt money market funds in Fidelity website.

Comment: Funds ending in XX are money market funds with constant $1.00 price (except in case of serious mismanagement). There's minor variation on the dividend rates, but unless you have vast sums of cash, the major players' offerings will be similar in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What funds/websites are you looking at? Here's a counterexample:

[Vanguard Prime Money Market Fund Investor Shares - VMMXX](http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/ratings-risk.action?t=VMMXX&region=usa&culture=en-US)

Edit after comment:

[Fidelity® Government Money Market Fund - SPAXX](http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/ratings-risk.action?t=SPAXX&region=usa&culture=en-US)

Comment: I was looking for risk parameters for SPAXX fund in Fidelity website. This fund is a government money market fund.

Comment: @Kannan Seems to be a question for Fidelity then.